# Node js & mongo API : Error: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Im trying to make an API with node JS (express and jwt) with a mongodb. 
I've make some routes (like to get markers for example), that's working fine.

BUT i've also make a route in order to post some markers. When I query it (that takes long time, and with Postman), and I've an error like : 
"Could not get any response"
and in my console : 
Error: socket hang up

My route controller :

```
const model = require('../models/markers');
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res, next) {
    model.create({
        param_1: req.body.param_1,
        param_2: req.body.param_2,
        param_3: req.body.param_3,
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
           next(err);
        else
            res.json({status: "success", message: "Marker added successfully", data: null});
    });
    },

    getAll: function(req, res, next) {
        let list = [];
        model.find({}, function(err, items){
            if (err){
                next(err);
            } else{
                for (let item of items) {
                    list.push({
                        id: item._id,
                        param_1: item.param_1,
                        param_2 : item.param_2,
                        param_3: item.param_3
                    });
                }
                res.json({status:"success", message: "Markers list found", data:{markers: list}});

            }
        });
    },
};
```

And for my route :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const markerController = require('../controllers/markers');

router.get('/', markerController.getAll);
router.post('/', markerController.create);
module.exports = router;
```

My model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const MarkerSchema = new Schema({
    param_1: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    param_2: {
        type: String,
    },
    param_3: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['0.5', '1', ',1.25', '1.5', '2', '3+']
        }],
        default: ['pending']
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Marker', MarkerSchema);
```

My get router works fine but my post route don't.

Comment: If your route controller is a copy/paste, there's a typo for starters…

Comment: I've edited some params, in my code there is not typo about this line, sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

You should check @Will Alexander comment, if it's a copy paste you have a typo in:

param_2: req.bodyparam_2,

Comment: You are using mongoose, and model.create requires a DB connection, do you have that set up?

Comment: How are you sending you requests for creation? is it postman? check if the data you're sending has a mistake or ur DB connection